# Crystal Reports - Browse Data Shows Nothing

Tags: oracle, crystal-reports

I just created a new table and filled it with data.  When I run a simple select query, I can see all the data.

But when I try to build a report in Crystal with this table, I get no data.  It doesn't matter if I have other tables included or not, so it isn't a linking issue.

If I right click a field and choose "browse data", I get nothing, which tells me that somehow Crystal can't read the data at all.

I created the table with the same user name/password that I used when connecting to the database from Crystal Reports.

Any ideas?

(If it matters, I'm using Oracle 10g Release 1 and Crystal Reports XI Release 2.  We use a direct Oracle connection, not an ODBC.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.  I hadn't yet committed the data on the database.

This taught me something about Oracle.  I rarely use the "commit" command - but when I have created tables and filled them with data it's been via a "select" statement.  Those tables have always worked.  This time I did it via the insert all command.  I needed to commit for that to work!

Comment: This sounds to me like you are new to Oracle databases. From Oracles own documentation, I would recommend to you the "Database Concepts" book, to get an overview.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

I am fairly new to Oracle - I used SQLServer for several years and I've only been using Oracle for about 8 months.  I'm not sure I need a database concepts book just b/c I'm comfortable with general concepts, I've had several database courses, and I've worked in DBs since 2002. But I've picked up some books to help me transition to Oracle.  

Re. this specific situation - I think there's an autocommit option I can turn on and I'm assuming it must be on by default in SQLServer since I never needed it except when working in transactions.

Comment: Oh good, you already have some literature to help find your way in the Oracle world. Just to clarify my intent: The book titled "Database Concepts" is part of the Oracle database documentation and it describes the concepts of an Oracle database, not of databases in general.